# Background not working for a div

Tags: css, html, background-image

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Think in a NEW BOX.
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/title-1.png" /><img src="images/title-2a.png" /><img src="images/title-3.png" /></div><div id="fcontent">
                hi
hi
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...and the following CSS:

```
div#fcontent{
        background-image:url('images/forground.png');
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }
```

My background isn't showing up, why is this?

Here is ALL of the CSS, just in case (the problem is probably in the CSS snippet above, however):

```
html, body {
        background-color:black;
        font-family:"arial bold";
        overflow:auto;
        text-align: center; 
        display: inline-block;
        color:white;
    }
div#content {
        width:792px;
        height:100%;
        padding:0px;
    }

div#header  {
        height:216px;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }

div#fcontent{
        background-image:url('images/forground.png');
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }

*           {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: I mean, "foreground" does have an "e" in it for starters. :)

Comment: Add a min-height to your fcontent and see if it works :) Also do you have a doctype?

Comment: Question for you: Does the background show up when you specify a `background-color`? One guess would be that your image path is wrong or doesn't exist.

Comment: The file name forground.png could be correct, but it also might be incorrect. What happens when you use a background color instead of a background image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that the path to the image is relative to the CSS file so if your CSS file is in a "styles" folder etc, the image currently being requested must be located in /styles/images/forground.png.

If you change the location of the url to an absolute URL such as from the root, then you can avoid this kind of problem.

```
url('/images/forground.png');
```

alternatively you might want to jump out of the current folder and then into the images folder:

```
url('../images/forground.png');
```

Hope thant helps.

Comment: I would have never expected that to be the problem.  I've always used CSS in the same file, this was the first time I've used an external CSS file.  THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing a DIV with the ID `fcontent` that could be the first issue.

Comment: Yep, I had to put them end to end to remove the slight spacing that IE likes to put in.

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted your code and it works for me in chrome and firefox.

Make sure your path to the image is correct, and you may want to try setting a height.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, this is the root path:

```
url('/images/forground.png');
```

Always referring to: www.yoursite.com/images/forground.png

While this are relative paths, which you should normally use:

```
url('images/forground.png');
url('../images/forground.png');
```

For more information you may look into this thread: [Background not working for a div as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541687/background-not-working-for-a-div-as-it-should)