# Background not working for a div as it should

Tags: css, url, html, background

I have a strange problem with paths, this one works (on Windows):

```
<div style="background:url('folder1/image.gif')...
```

But this one won't work (no image shows up):

```
<div style="background:url('/folder1/image.gif')...
```

Still this page says exactly the opposite (not the first but the second version should work): [Background not working for a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062336/background-not-working-for-a-div)

Anybody knowing what the reason might be?

Comment: Is folder1 a library of the root?

Comment: No, it isn't, otherwise it would have worked. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first url is relative to the folder in server what your HTML is used to render the page.

Example, if you get:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.html
```

it will look into: *(example 2)*

```
www.mywebsite.com/folder1/image.gif
```

but if you are in another folder like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/index.html
```

It will look in:

```
www.mywebsite.com/subfolder/folder1/image.gif
```

If you use a '/' in the beggin, the path isn't more relative, it always look in the root website, like exemple 2 no matter where your html is located.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a relative path, the second is an absolute path

Relative paths show the file path from the calling context.  So if your html file is  /source/website/test.html, a relative path of `css/test.css` will point to a file in `/source/website/css/test.css`

Absolute paths show relate to the whole path, so `/css/test.css` tries to find a file at the location `/css/test.css`

Comment: So this thread seems to be wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062336/background-not-working-for-a-div

Comment: Well the accepted answer in that thread doesn't say the difference between the root path and the relative path. Gabriel's answer a lot more clear than the answer in that thread.

Comment: I think it assumed that information, but its still accurate.  If you think Gabriel's answer was helpful you should upvote it and accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where your image and html file are located.

`'folder1/image.gif'` will search for a folder1 that is located in the same path as your html file (relative path).

`'/folder1/image.gif'` will search for a folder1 starting from the base location of your server (absolute path).

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers allow you to inspect elements on a web page. On chrome (or other modern browser) open the console and look for errors, if the image url is wrong, the console will indicate it as an error, moreover you will get the broken-image icon if you have specified the wrong url

[image: image-1]